# The alpha value doesn't work if ArrayList is involved

Tags: java, arraylist, colors

Shorty, I have a ArrayList that stores multiple objects to itself. Everytime when I draw those objects, i also do set the color to a greenish color. My problem is, the alpha value is being somehow completely overseen. Why? (But not the actual Color, so just the alpha value doesn't show up).

I firstly tried to do the ordinary way with setColor method. But that didn't worked. I also wrote a method that made sure that i go over all of the objects. That didn't worked either.

The usual way to do this: (didn't worked)

```java
private void drawWatchers(Graphics2D g) {
   for (int i = 0; i < watcher.size(); i++) {
       g.setColor(new Color(46, 139, 87, 150));
       g.fillRect(watcher.get(i).getX(), watcher.get(i).getY(), 30, 30);
   }
}
```

The code that i have written to be sure that i am going through all the objects
(didn't worked either)

```java
public Color setColor(int r, int g, int b, int a){
   return new Color(r, g, b, a);
}

//On the other class:

for (int i = 0; i < watcher.size(); i++) {
      g.setColor(watcher.get(i).setColor(46, 139, 87, 150));
      g.fillRect(watcher.get(i).getX(), watcher.get(i).getY(), 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: More like a code review, but the method name `setColor` is misleading since it does not really set anything for the instance. `createColor` or similar might be better, however if it will only call the `Color` constructor, it might be worth it to call the constructor directly and not introduce a separate method for this.

Comment: @Marcono1234 You didn't answer my question. The method was a test to see whether it affects anything or whether it's the solution to my problem. So don't get to confused with that method. It was a test.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I was feeding more objects to the ArrayList, which resulted in not drawing in the corrected Color. It is very interesting though to see, why the actual Color is being shown but not the alpha value. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: I also answered to that question by myself as well. The problem was, that, it is actually being drawn but since it is a transparency value, the objects is being overlapped and the color looks like, it never took an alpha value.